# ANCOVA: Calculate $\omega^2$ for two factorial design

Tags: effect-size, ancova

I am trying to calculate the $\omega^2$ effect size for a two factorial (with two levels each) effect size for an ANCOVA with one covariate. Following deliberations from Howell (2012) I got the following formula for first calculating the variance components for each of the main and interaction effects (my two factors are called MC and TV):
$$
\begin{align}
\tilde{\sigma}^2_{MC} &= \frac{MS_{MC} - MS_R}{4n_{MC}}\\
\tilde{\sigma}^2_{TV} &= \frac{MS_{TV} - MS_R}{4n_{TV}}\\
\tilde{\sigma}^2_{MC\times TV} &= \frac{MS_{MC\times TV} - MS_R}{4n_{MC\times TV}}
\end{align}
$$

And calculating the final effect size based upon this like that:
$$
\omega^2 = \frac{\tilde{\sigma}^2}{\tilde{\sigma}^2_{MC}+\tilde{\sigma}^2_{TV}+\tilde{\sigma}^2_{MC\times TV}+MS_R}
$$

However this formula doesn't seem to include yet the effect of the covariate. Does anyone know how I can include it to calculate the $\omega^2$ effect size?